# Possible value to an equation: m=45/2n-1

Tags: probability, statistics

If $m=\frac{45}{2n} −1$ and both $m$ and $n$ are positive whole numbers, what is the average value of all possible values of $n$? The answer is 7?

I am not quite sure where to start. $m$ and $n$ can be any whole numbers?

Comment: Is it $\frac{45}{2n}-1$ or $\frac{45}{2n-1}$?

Comment: Depending on whether it is $\frac{45}{2n-1}$ or $\frac{45}{2n} - 1$ the answer changes.

Comment: I think it has to be $\frac{45}{2n-1}$. There are no possible values for the other one.

Comment: Yes it is
values of n are 1 + 2 + 3 + 5 + 8 + 23 = 42
and 42/6 = 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are given
$$m=\frac{45}{2n-1}$$
Then you can start by multiplying both sides by $2n-1$ to get
$$(2n-1)m=45$$
Now it would be useful to list out all of the factors of $45$. We have
$$1\times45=45$$
$$3\times15=45$$
$$5\times9=45$$
$$9\times5=45$$
$$15\times3=45$$
$$45\times1=45$$
Thus the possible values of $2n-1$ are $1,3,5,9,15,$and $45$, and so the possible values of $n$ are $1,2,3,5,8,$ and $23$, whose average is $7$.

Comment: Don't you mean multiply by 2n - 1 to get m(2n - 1) = 45?

Comment: @PeldePinda Oh yeah, sorry. :P Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: rewriting gives (2n - 1)m = 45. Since 2n - 1 and m are integers and $45 = 3^2\cdot5$ you can count all possible values for 2n - 1 and calculate the possible values of n from that.

Answer (score 0):

By using the [divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) $\sigma_x$, this can answered with a formula. The function $\sigma_0(n)$ gives the number of divisors of $x$, and $\sigma_1(x)$ gives the sum of the divisors.

So $\frac{\sigma_1(n)}{\sigma_0(n)}$ is the average of the divisors of $n$. And $\left(\frac{\sigma_1(45)}{\sigma_0(45)}+1\right)/2=(\frac{78}{6}+1)/2$ is the answer to the problem.